# what does /../ or "/../" mean in file system?

Tags: php, laravel, directory, filesystems

I know that . refers to current directory and ./ refers to files in current directory.
I also know that .. refers to parent directory

Recently i came across the following line:

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

(It was in laravel's index.php file.)

Here specifically what is meant by "/../"?

Thanks

Edit : I tried searching on google. I tried searching using escape sequences too like //..//, but it didn't give required answer.

Comment: that line refers to the autoloading of classes in laravel. i think its better not to touch that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You read it like this:

```
__DIR__      // start in the current directory
../          // go up one directory from where you are
vendor/      // go into the vendor directory
autoload.php // and require the autoload.php file
```

The extra `/` between `__DIR__` and `../` is just to ensure the current directory ends in a slash, so you get, for instance `code/../vendor/autoload.php` instead of `code../vendor/autoload.php`

Answer (score 0):

In paths `.` referes to the current (working-)directory and `..` referes to parent directory (if exist). Both are "shortcuts" for actual writing the named of those directories (If for example you don't know the name of the current/parent directory): Here is an example:

If you are in folder `/root`:

```
1  ./test        //--> points to folder 'test' (relative path)
2  /root/test    //--> points to folder 'test' (absolut path)
```

both are equal. And if you are in folder `/root/test`:

```
1  ./..          //--> points to folder 'root' (relative path)
2  /root         //--> points to folder 'root' (absolut path)
```

Answer (score 0):

`../` go up to the parent directory and then be in the same root director of the project `/` before `../`

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

It referees to the parent directory of the current path (of curse if the parent directory exists).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `/../` doesn't have any specific definition because it is the part of `__DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php'` which consisted of `..` and `/vendor/autoload.php`. Which `..` means go back to current parent directory and the later tells you to enter or `cd` to `vendor` directory then proceed to `autoload.php`, and everything relative to `__DIR__`.

Example:

Imagine you want to `gedit` a file in another directory from your current directory which structured below

```
/home/handsomeyou/Documents/Code/ -> your current directory
/home/hansdomeyou/Documents/Tasks/task_list.txt -> your target
```

There are many approach to achieve this, but to make it relevant to your question, we will do this

```
$ gedit ../Tasks/task_list.txt
```